# Embedded Jetty Defining Realm without Jetty.xml

Tags: java, basic-authentication, embedded-jetty, jetty-8

I use embedded Jetty at my application and I don't want to use an external xml file (jetty.xml). I want to implement a security layer. This is what I want to do:

```
<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
  <Set name="contextPath">/test</Set>
  <Set name="war"><SystemProperty name="jetty.home" default="."/>/webapps/test</Set>

  <Get name="securityHandler">
    <Set name="loginService">
      <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.security.HashLoginService">
            <Set name="name">Test Realm</Set>
            <Set name="config"><SystemProperty name="jetty.home" default="."/>/etc/realm.properties</Set>
      </New>
    </Set>
  </Get>

</Configure>
```

How can I add it into my embedded jetty without a jetty.xml (I'll just use realm.properties as an external file).

[Embedded Jetty](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Tutorial/Embedding_Jetty)

[Jetty Realms](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Tutorial/Realms)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how it is done:

```
Server server = new Server();

Connector connector = new SelectChannelConnector();
connector.setPort(8080);
server.setConnectors(new Connector[]{connector});

WebAppContext webappcontext = new WebAppContext();
webappcontext.setContextPath("/mywebapp");
webappcontext.setWar("./path/to/my/war/orExplodedwar");

HandlerCollection handlers= new HandlerCollection();
handlers.setHandlers(new Handler[]{webappcontext, new DefaultHandler()});

server.setHandler(handlers);
HashUserRealm myrealm = new HashUserRealm("MyRealm",System.getProperty("jetty.home")+"/etc/realm.properties");
server.setUserRealms(new UserRealm[]{myrealm});

server.start();
server.join();
```

[Jetty Documentation](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/How+to+Configure+Security+with+Embedded+Jetty)